# move old data in Mongodb to other Mongodb server

Tags: mongodb, server

I have 4 servers which run same application. applications saves data in Mongodb database. These data are historical and are not used in application itself. Each of these 4 servers have limited amount of hard memory, so everyday I should move old data in mongodb to another mongodb server (backup server) to keep more space available in hard memories of the servers . What is the best practice to do this?

Comment: I think you should look for an automated backup scenaio. I suggest looking at this link If it did not help I will provide you another explanation.https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-scheduled-logical-mongodb-backups-to-digitalocean-spaces

Comment: @pooriataghizadeh thanks for you attention. This tutorial explains how to backup regularly, but my issue is to move (cut) data of yesterday to another mongodb server and clean them in original database. My initial plan is to have python script which runs regularly and copies data to another database and clean the data in original database. but i think it's not best way